# How can i duplicate a wordpress plugin to three or more

Tags: wordpress, plugins, duplicates, copy

How can I duplicate a WordPress plugin so that there are three or more of the same plugins running. And that there is no conflict between them. I hope help me with that.

This is the plugin: [GD-mylist](https://github.com/andygi/GD-mylist)

Comment: why you want to duplicate the plugin ?

Comment: I would like to customize the plugin with more than one method for my website , like this (completed) , (watching) , (Plan to watch) , (favorite) , (On-Hold) , (Dropped)

Comment: @dipmala I hope if you have solution that will help me

Comment: Then you need to copy the plugin but give its different name

Comment: @dipmala I had already done so but unfortunately did not work

Comment: then you should post the code with error which kind of error you are facing?

Comment: @dipmala When I duplicate the add-on with all the titles changing there is still overlap between them where only one out of 4 will work

Comment: without checking the error we can't help, WP_DEBUG to true and debug the code